# How to customize the proof name without affecting the \qed positioning?

Tags: proof-package

everybody.
I need to customize the proof name as "Demostración" underlined and with a linebreak after that proof name.  I have tried with these codes.  I'm going to tell you what I got with each one and what I couldn't get.

```
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\bfseries \underline{Demostración} \newline}
```

With this one I couldn't underline the proofname nor the linebreak, but \qedhere works perfectly.

```
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\it \underline{Demostración} \newline}}{\qed}
```

With this second one I could underline the proof name and get the linebreak, but \qedhere doesn't work with lists (\enumerate or \itemize environments).

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname] {\par\pushQED{\qed}\normalfont    \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax\trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep\it\underline{#1}%
\@addpunct{}\newline]\ignorespaces}{\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother
```

With this last one I couldn't get the underlined proof name, nor the linebreak, but \qedhere works perfctly.

What else can I do in order to customize the \proof environmen as I need?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make it a theorem-like structure. With `ntheorem`, you have this theorem style  pre-defined (`nonumberbreak`).